# How can I execute mjs files (node.js modules) inside Vim with the terminal command?

Tags: terminal, filetype-javascript

Let's say I have a pure node.js `file.js` as the following:

```javascript
const fs = require('fs')
console.log("Hello World")
```

If I execute it inside Vim with `:%terminal node` it works perfectly fine. I see the same results I'd see executing it from the command line with `node file.js`.

My problem starts with node.js modules. On node.js, modules are `.mjs` files. Let's say I have the following `file.mjs` code:

```javascript
import fs from 'fs'
console.log('Hello World')
```

The way node.js differentiates a module from a normal file is by its file extension, `js` files are pure node.js and `mjs` files are modules. Both of them can be executed from the command line as isolated scripts with the commands `node file.js` and `node file.mjs`. However, if I try to execute this `mjs` file with `:%terminal node` inside Vim it gives me the error :

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside module
```

That's exactly the same error I'd receive if I had renamed `file.mjs` to `file.js` and tried to execute it with `node file.js`. My assumption is that Vim sees it as a `js` file even though its extension is `mjs`...

When I run `:echo &ft` inside Vim it prints `javascript` for both `mjs` and `js` files. I'm not completely sure if what I want to do is possible. From the command line it works perfectly fine executing `mjs` files, but if I try executing them from Vim with the `:terminal` command, like `:%terminal node`, it fails. Does anyone have any idea of a workaround for this issue? In a way that allows me to execute node.js modules from inside Vim?

Comment: You would probably be better off with `:terminal node %`—the range version using the lines as input, while the argument version gives the file name to the node process

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You're right, when I use `:terminal node %` it executes the `mjs` file properly. However, I lose the ability to select lines and execute only them doing that. That was an important feature for me... So, apparently the problem is that Vim creates a `js` file with the selected lines when I use the range version. Then when it tries to execute it it won't be seen as a module. I'm not sure if I can change this behavior with the range version... I'm considering creating a function that creates a temporary `mjs` file with the selected lines just for executing it with a second command.

Comment: Not quite: `:%terminal node` runs node and passes each line in the buffer to the node REPL by giving the line to the process's input. You do have the module part right, but there's no extra files or anything, just stdin. You could create a temp file as you mentioned though.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Just as a curiosity that's not related to the question. But if Vim uses stdin to execute files when we use the `%terminal node` syntax. Does that mean that it'd be possible to continuously execute parts of the code inside the same terminal? So we can create something like a Jupyter notebook just using Vim?

Comment: Anything seems possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, I ended up writing a function that writes the selection content inside a temporary file. My vimrc file is as the following now:

```
function! ExecuteOnTerminal(type) range
    if (expand("%:e")=='mjs') " check if extension of file is mjs
        if a:type == "V"
            '<,'>w! /tmp/file.mjs
        else
            :w! /tmp/file.mjs
        endif
        :vert botright terminal node /tmp/file.mjs
    elseif (&ft=='javascript') " check if filetype is javascript
        if a:type == "V"
            :vert botright '<,'> %terminal node
        else
            :vert botright %terminal node
        endif
    endif
endfunction

vnoremap <silent> <F6> :call ExecuteOnTerminal("V")<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <F6> :call ExecuteOnTerminal("I")<CR>
```

Basically, I'm doing the following:

1. Getting the extension of the file that's being executed with `expand("%:e")`.
2. If it's `mjs` file, I write a temporary file with the selected lines or the entire file.
3. Executing this temporary file with `:terminal node /tmp/file.mjs`.
4. In case it doesn't have the `mjs` extension and is a `javascript` file I execute it normally with `:%terminal node`.